# Access datediff using calculated first day of the year

Tags: date, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm creating a new form in Access 2010.  I need to create a field that will calculate a year to date timeframe, in months, using a calculated value for the first day of the year.  The scenario is that the user will input a date.  Then, Access will calculate a value for months YTD, based on the date the user keys.  The catch is that the user may input a date for the current year, or a date from a previous year.  So, I cannot simply hard code a baseline date, like 1/1/2014, to perform the calculation.  I need Access to generate the first day of the year, based on the date entered, then perform the calculation.

Example:  User enters '4/10/2013'

Access calculates months YTD from '1/1/2013' to '4/10/2013'.

Expected Result:    3.25 Months

I need this to assist with calculating income, which will utilize dates over multiple years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quickly created this function for you:

```
Public Function calcmonths(datecalc As Date) As Double

    calcmonths = Round(DateDiff("d", DateSerial(Year(datecalc), 1, 1), datecalc) * 12 / DateDiff("d", DateSerial(Year(datecalc), 1, 1), DateSerial(Year(datecalc) + 1, 1, 1)), 2)
End Function
```

You can use it with the input from your form. It calculates the first day of the entered year with `DateSerial(Year(datecalc), 1, 1)` , then calculates the difference in days. That result is multiplied by 12 (months) and divided by the number of days within that year (calculated to make sure leap years are 366 days). In the end the result is rounded to 2 decimal numbers.